# Swagger stats to be hidden from public

Tags: node.js, api, docker, swagger

I have a set of public facing APIs and I have built swagger-stats to monitor them. But I don't want the public to access them but only access them internally, how can I achieve this?

My setup is, nodejs application runs in a docker container and nginx is used for routing. There is a load banalcer in front so all the request comes from one IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker-compose could be use for this, it allow to easily setup multiple containers,
`Links` will allow linking between docker containers and `EXPOSE` to have port accessible from other containers but not from host.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/